# How to make Bootstrap 3 tooltip follow mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of links on my site that are showing images in a Bootstrap tooltip

```
<a data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='1.png' />">Item 1</a>
<a data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='2.png' />">Item 2</a>
<a data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<img src='3.png' />">Item 3</a>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').tooltip({
            placement: "right"
        })
    }

</script>
```

This just brings up the tooltip to the right of all the links. The images are static though, I'd like the tooltip image to move around as the user moves their mouse around.

You can see an example of what I want to do on this site: http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/381677-druidereno. On the right sidebar, there's a list of cards you can hover over, and the tooltip images follow the mouse movement. Doesn't look like they use Bootstrap, I just want to emulate the functionality.

I don't see anything to do this in the Bootstrap functionality: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 14):

You cannot do that natively in bootstrap. But you can easily mimick the behaviour by using a "proxy element". The trick is to attach the image tooltip to a second element and then update that elements position according to the mouse position when you move the mouse cursor around inside the image.

An image :

```html
<img id="img" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/6555/nature-sunset-person-woman-large.jpg" />
```

A proxy element, here an `<i>` tag with `trigger: manual`  :

```html
<i id="img-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip for image" data-animation="false" data-trigger="manual"/>
```

Set the proxy elements `position` to `absolute` so it can be moved around anywhere :

```css
#img-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Finally update the proxys position and show the tooltip when you move the mouse cursor around inside the image :

```js
$("#img").on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $("#img-tooltip").css({top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX });
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show')
})
$("#img").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide')
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/h2dL07ns/**

---

Updated demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/h2dL07ns/324/** using @Marks's `pointer-events: none;` suggestion. It removes any occasional flickering.

Comment: Seems like this is close to what is needed but I found an issue. Once the window is scrolled, the tooltip aligns to the top of the image. This issue is reproducible in your fiddle as well.

Comment: This is a great solution! But the mouseleave is getting triggered when moving over the tooltip itself, creating some flicker.

Comment: I would recommend using `pointer-events: none;` for the tooltip element. A CSS selector such as this would work: `#img-tooltip + .tooltip`. This will prevent the flicker issue.

Answer (score 2):

enhanced davickon answer for multiple images

```js
$(".img").on('mousemove', function(e) {

  $("#" + $(this).attr("TooltipId")).css({
    top: e.pageY,
    left: e.pageX
  });

  $("#" + $(this).attr("TooltipId")).tooltip('show');
  $(".tooltip-inner").css({
    "background-color": $(this).attr("TooltipBackround")
  });
  var a = ($("#" + $(this).attr("TooltipId")).attr("data-placement") != "") ? $("#" + $(this).attr("TooltipId")).attr("data-placement") : "top";
  $(".tooltip-arrow").css("border-" + a + "-color", $(this).attr("TooltipBackround"));
})

$(".img").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $("#" + $(this).attr("TooltipId")).tooltip('hide')
})
```

```css
.img-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h1>header</h1>
<img class="img" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/6555/nature-sunset-person-woman-large.jpg" TooltipBackround="green" TooltipId="img-tooltip1" />
<i id="img-tooltip1" class="img-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip for image <h1>Faizan</h1>" data-animation="false" data-trigger="manual"></i>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img class="img" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/6555/nature-sunset-person-woman-large.jpg" TooltipBackround="blue" TooltipId="img-tooltip2" />
<i id="img-tooltip2" class="img-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="right" data-animation="false" data-trigger="manual" title="Tooltip for image <h1>Faizan Anwer</h1>"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind the "mousemove" event listener to the document. Capture the e.pageX, e.pageY movement of the mouse and set the "displayed" tooltip position to where the mouse is. (Requires jQuery)

```
    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if( $('div.tooltip').css('display') !== 'hidden' ) {
            var toolHalfHeight = $('div.tooltip').outerHeight() / 2;
            $('div.tooltip').css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY - toolHalfHeight);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with angularjs and facing a similar problem. There is no in built functionality in bootstrap for this. I also tried using a proxy element. But, it was causing a lot of problems. For eg. I was not able to click on element below the proxy element. I found one workaround. It is hacky and unsuggested.

You can get a DOM element in your browser console on creating a tooltip by setting tooltip attribute of the element, on which you want to see tooltip. I copied that DOM element and pasted it in my html, exactly where it was in DOM and removed the previously used tooltip attribute. It worked for me and gave me much more flexibility with the tooltip. You would have to remove some attributes and do some other minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

Using Faizan's code and responding to T3db0t's concerns about flickering, I found that sticking in a non-breaking space, adding visibility: hidden to the css, and closing the proxy element tag reduced the flickering.

Basically speaking:

```
<i>&#160;</i>
```

With css:

```
.area-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

See my pen: https://codepen.io/Larhanya/pen/VMjZBz
(code tweaked for an image map since that's what I needed)

Truncated HTML from the pen:

```
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-350-350-5.jpg" usemap="#foodmap">
    <map id="#foodmap" name="foodmap">
      <area class="area" shape="poly" coords="78,133,158,182,162,349,0,349,0,283" href="#" target="_self" style="outline:none;" TooltipBackround="black" TooltipId="area-tooltip4" />
      <i id="area-tooltip4" class="area-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="right" title="Pepper" data-animation="false" data-trigger="manual">&#160;</i>
    </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any of the answers here worked for Bootstrap 4. Here was my solution:

```
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').forEach(function (tooltipElement) {
    tooltipElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function (MouseEvent) {
      const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');
      if (tooltip)
      {
        tooltip.style.transform = 'none';
        tooltip.style.top = MouseEvent.clientY + 10 + 'px';
        tooltip.style.left = MouseEvent.clientX + 10 + 'px';
      }
    });
  });
```

First we get every element that has a tooltip. Then we add an event listener to each of these elements for mousemove. Using the MouseEvent we can repeatedly rewrite the top & left styles to move the tooltip with the cursor.

We remove the transform styles as these can push the tooltip away from the cursor.

If you want to prevent your tooltips from overflowing the right of the screen you can rework the end of the above function like so:

```
  if (tooltip)
  {
    tooltip.style.transform = 'none';
    tooltip.style.top = MouseEvent.clientY + 10 + 'px';
    tooltip.style.left = MouseEvent.clientX + 10 + 'px';

    //if mouseevent is within 100px of the right edge of the screen
    if (MouseEvent.clientX > window.innerWidth - 100)
    {
      //move the tooltip to the left of the mouse
      tooltip.style.transform = 'translateX(-100%)';
    }
  }
```